# Windows Azure node.js Push notification for Windows store 8.1 - How to use 'createRawTemplateRegistration' template?

Tags: node.js, azure, push-notification, windows-8.1, wns

Please explain with one example as I am getting Error: 400 - The specified resource description is invalid.

Basically, I want to update badge value. But there is no template for badge registration in WnsService API document (http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/WnsService.html). So, I am trying with "createRawTemplateRegistration" template to update the badge value.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the function [`sendBadge()`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/WnsService.html#sendBadge) to push badge value to client devices.

Please try the following code:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService('<hubname>', '<connectionstring>');
notificationHubService.wns.sendBadge(null,99,function(error,response){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
})
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

### update

Do you mean that you want only one template and to handle all the types of notifications including Raw, Toast, Badge? If so, I think the answer is negative. According the description http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/WnsService.html#createRawTemplateRegistration:

> Remember that you have to specify the X-WNS-Type header

So the header option is required. And according the REST API which is invoked via this api in nodejs is [Create Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx), and we can find the description:

> The BodyTemplate element is mandatory, as is the X-WNS-Type header.

So we should specify the notification type for the template.

## update1

This code sample works fine on my side:

```
var channel = '<devicetoken>';
var templateMessage = { text1: '$(message)' }; 
notificationHubService.wns.createRawTemplateRegistration(channel,'tag',JSON.stringify(templateMessage), {headers: { 'X-WNS-Type': 'wns/raw' }},
    function (e, r) {
        if (e) {
            console.log(e);
        } else {
            console.log({
                id: r.RegistrationId,
                deviceToken: r.DeviceToken,
                expires: r.ExpirationTime
            });
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Yes, sendBadge() can be used but that would need server side changes. right?
I wanted to register one template on azure and push should be received according to that template every time without changes at the server side. 

For eg. I have registered this template to receive toast push. Same I want for badge value update.

templateMessage = { text1: '$(message)' };
hub.wns.createToastText01Registration(pushIdentifier,
                   [userId, platform, version, tag], templateMessage, registrationComplete);

Comment: As badge template in UWP is a special type of xml string, and which seems couldn't be customized, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779719.aspx for details. The entire badge string is `<badge value="<value>"/>`, and the acceptable value type are numeric character or predefined strings in UWP system.

Comment: So is it not possible to register some template for badge on azure like we did for toast.? (template for toast is provided in my earlier comment.). From server I am getting two things. 1. Message 2. Count
This count can be utilised to update the badge. But for that I need one template registered on azure. Hope you are getting my question. Please ask if you need more info.

Comment: As the length limitation of comment, refer to the update. If anything I have misunderstood, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It is not necessary that one template should handle all types of notification i.e. badge ,toast etc. 
I want badge registration template to register on azure. But I found that there is no badge registration template. There is only sendbadge() template. So I have thought to use 'createRawTemplateRegistration' template for that purpose as in that header type I can specify "wns/badge". This is the template format : createRawTemplateRegistration(channel, tags, template, optionsOrCallbackopt, callback).

Comment: In this what should be "template" argument. Please explain me with one example. and let me know is it the right way to register on azure for badge update.

Comment: However, if you want to register a badge template, and try to use (send())[http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/mpnsservice.js.html#line605] function to send the template badge notification, I still don't think so, because the `type` param only available for `wns/raw, wns/tile and wns/toast`, no badge.

Comment: I dont want to use sendBadge() template on azure as its useful to send badge for one time only. I want one registration template for badge which can be registered once and then badge will be updated according to that. Like there is registration template for Toast i.e. createToast*Registration(channel, tags, template, optionsopt, callback)

Comment: Sorry, it seems currently, there is no API supports for your requirement.

Comment: Liu Could you just help me with 'createRawTemplateRegistration(channel, tags, template, optionsOrCallbackopt, callback)'? Please explain it with one example that what should be parameters.